# Which SE site should I ask a question regarding the design, invention and production of laboratory equipment and procedures?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which SE site should I ask a question regarding the design, invention and production of laboratory equipment and procedures?

Say I have questions regarding the design, invention and production of laboratory equipment and procedures. For example:

> (1) Are there open-source robotics for the design/production of an
> automated chemical synthesis machine?

> (2) Is there a systematic
> process (similar to, for example, the drug discovery and development
> cycle in
> https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drug_discovery_cycle.svg) that
> one can follow in the improvement and invention of existing analytical
> procedures in chemistry?

Where should I post them?

Related to this is the question on what field these questions/topics to. I do welcome some side comments and thoughts on whether, in the above:

- question (1) is an issue in the domain of synthetic chemistry, or
  that of engineering (and if engineering, is it chemical engineering,
  or is it also electrical engineering and mechanical engineering)
- question (2) is an issue in the domain of analytical chemistry, or
  that of engineering (and if engineering, is it chemical engineering,
  or is it also electrical engineering and mechanical engineering)

Comment: This seems too niche for any existing site.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you  read through the help center for [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) to see what is on-topic there, and perhaps searching on their Meta site.

To me, the first question sounds too broad  for the Stack Exchange format and thus not a good fit for any site; SE is for concrete problems you face.  For the second one, I suggest checking whether it appears to be on-topic for Chemistry.SE.